# AWS Micro Instance - MySQL keeps failing in Wordpress installation

Tags: mysql, wordpress, amazon-web-services

I have a Ubuntu micro instance with default settings. As a matter of fact, this instance is the same as 8 others I have created prior and since to host Wordpress websites.

This one belongs to a Church, and unfortunately, it keeps having its MySql server going to heaven! I am not sure how to sort this, as the `mysql.err` log shows:

```
160301  5:03:40 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in$
160301  5:03:40 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
160301  5:03:40 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160301  5:03:40 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
160301  5:03:40 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
160301  5:03:40 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
160301  5:03:40 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
160301  5:03:40 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160301  5:03:40 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
160301  5:03:40 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
160301  5:03:40 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
160301  5:03:40 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
160301  5:03:40 [ERROR] Aborting

160301  5:03:40 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

This is telling me it could not allocate the `128MB` required for the buffer pool.

But, my `free -m` shows there is plenty of memory for this (I also set up a 2GB swap).

```
ubuntu@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx:/var/log/mysql$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           992        634        358         54         76        308
-/+ buffers/cache:        249        742
Swap:         2047          0       2047
```

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is not enough memory left for allocation during the start process.

**add this to your /etc/mysql/my.cnf**

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 20M
```